# Filter Items in a List in a Pandas Column

Tags: python, pandas

**I have a df column like this:**

```
col1
[('asd', 0.99), ('vcxx', 0.77), ('dfs', 0.32)]
[('fds', 0.97), ('xcvxc', 0.71), ('vcbtxx', 0.54), ('bfed', 0.12)]
[('fdssa', 0.98), ('asdfd', 0.61)]
```

I'm trying to create a function that i can apply to a new column and it will insert the list elements that are **> .75**

**Like this:**

```
new_col
[('asd', 0.99), ('vcxx', 0.77)]
[('fds', 0.97)]
[('fdssa', 0.98)]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['new_col'] = df.col1.apply(lambda x: [val for val in x if val[1] > 0.75])
```

Comment: one more question on this - what if I wanted to grab all the numbers in each of those lists, and put them in a corresponding column?

Comment: `df.col1.apply(lambda x: [val[1] for val in x if val[1] > 0.75])` just store the number in list